# probability of a row in one dataframe occurring in another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-wrangling

I have 2 dataframes

df 1 (films sent to users):

```
    UserID  Film 
    1       3
    2       41
    2       23
    2       53
    3       34
    5       6
```

df 2 (films watched by users - subset of df 1):

```
    UserID  Film 
    1       3
    2       41
    5       6
```

I'm trying to create a column in df1 which is the probability of a user watching a film, like this

```
    UserID  Film  Probability
    1       3     1
    2       41    0.33
    2       23    0.33   
    2       53    0.33
    3       34    0
    5       6     1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with `indicator` parameter and then check if `both` values with [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) `mean` for probalility:

```
df = df1.merge(df2, indicator='Probability', how='left')

df['Probability'] = df['Probability'].eq('both').groupby(df['UserID']).transform('mean')
print (df)
  UserID  Film  Probability
0       1     3     1.000000
1       2    41     0.333333
2       2    23     0.333333
3       2    53     0.333333
4       3    34     0.000000
5       5     6     1.000000
```